# Form.io Dynamic Select Filtering how to passing two params

Tags: javascript, angular, formio

In Form.io when Data Source Type in URL.

how filter with two params of dynamic values in filter query in Form.io

`date={{data.date}}&agentid={{data.agentid}}`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you need to provide the parameters as follows.

```
?data.date={{data.date}}&data.agentid={{data.agentid}}
```